# Creating an array of Command Buttons

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-word, commandbutton, control-array

I am in a situation Where I need to Create multiple `Command buttons` and assign a single `event handler` to these buttons using following Event Handler.

```
Private Sub Digits_Click(Index as Integer)
Display.Caption=Display.Caption+Digits(Index).Caption
End Sub
```

I created first button and copy paste it to the `userform` but it did not Prompt:

"You already have a control Name XXX. Do you want to create a control array?"

VBA doesn’t allow us to to create Control Array like in VB6 and VB.Net. My Question is Can we still create Control Array in VBA??
I am new to this Topic Please help

Comment: http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/15/vba-control-arrays/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at creating a loop and dynamically adding the command buttons

Every cmd should have a unique name.. It can call the same sub procedure. But every button should be unique in its own sense.

Comment: VBA doesn’t allow us to to create Control Array like in VB6 and VB.Net. My Question is Can we still create Control Array in VBA??

Comment: In that case you will have to use a class module to create a control array...coz I can think of no other way to do this in vba than a creating a class

Comment: Dos this use existing textboxes in the UserForm and assigning a same set of event procedures?? or I need to Create dynamic Userform